# How to let Validation control and custom javascript validation function work together?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm developing a web application. At first I use validation control to do required field validation, later I need to add some custom function to do the validation but still need required field validation. The problem is I found after I add onclientcliek event of the submit button, the previous validation control does not fired. Is there a way that could let both the validation control and my javascript function work before submit the form? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using a CustomValidator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have an ID on your submit button and try and put something like this in your document.ready function:

```
$("#YourSubmitButtonId").click(function(){
       yourValidationFunction();
       return false;
 });
```

Comment: how to call from within the required validation function?

Comment: ignore previous suggestion, try my edit up there to see if that works

Comment: The click function is not trigered. I figured out that if use clientvalidation, you'd better not use asp.net validaton server control, or you use customvalidator control. But it has some limitations. No wonder peole write validation code by themselves. Thanks though.

Comment: But how to pass the verification, since it always returns false

Comment: this is just a click function. returning false here actually has nothing to do with the actual validation, it just prevents the click from doing its default behavior, the submit (i.e. making it so you can do both the client and server side validation). the yourValidationFunction() is what is going to determine if your validation is correct. is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomValidator Control. It is pretty easy to configure your own Client-side Validation. More info and an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic7). Both validation controls can then work side by side.